# Multiple threads reading from the same file sharing one handler

Tags: multithreading, file, c++11

C++11, multiplatform code, threads with `std::thread`. I have one open file and multiple threads that have to read from it.

Premise: at first I only had one string that held the path to the file, then each new thread opened the file, read from it, then closed it. This worked well but at some point I realized it was maybe a bit slow for my purpose. So I now have a `FILE*` that is opened in the class constructor and closed in the destroy, and multiple threads reading from the same file. Only reading, no writing.

I know this has been long discussed in other questions, but I haven't found an answer to my specific questions, that are:

1) is it safe to do so?
2) is it actually faster to have multiple threads accessing the same handler rather than having each thread doing the open/close tasks?
3) can the O.S. interfere in some way with my threads?

Some example code:

BEFORE (thread opens/closes the file):

```
void continuePreload(int sn, unsigned long ByteSize)
{
    // Open file
    FILE *fpFile = fopen(openFile, "rb");
    // Seek position
    fseek(fpFile, WavePointers[sn] + preloadByteSize[sn], SEEK_SET);
    // Read portion
    fread(&SampleData[sn][preloadByteSize[sn] / sizeof(short)], 1, ByteSize - preloadByteSize[sn], fpFile);
    // Close file
    fclose(fpFile);
}
```

NOW (thread accesses an already open file):

```
void continuePreload(int sn, unsigned long ByteSize)
{
    // No need to open/close the file again, just seek the position...
    fseek(openFP, WavePointers[sn] + preloadByteSize[sn], SEEK_SET);
    // And read the desired data
    fread(&SampleData[sn][preloadByteSize[sn] / sizeof(short)], 1, ByteSize - preloadByteSize[sn], openFP);
}
```

Comment: If you're only reading, is there a reason you don't read the entire file in memory and have your threads read from there (file size would be a reason I guess)

Comment: You use `seeks`, besides the reading changes the internal pointer so I doubt your code is correct(it is UB actually, I believe). Use 2 handlers. That won't be a bottleneck for sure.

Comment: I'm afraid you're darn right... Just now I'm experiencing some malfunctioning, as the waveform (as the variable names suggest, I'm dealing with audio) seems to jump from one position to another, it must be because one thread moves the position pointer while another one was still reading.

Answer (score 0):

The code is wrong. You have a race with multiple threads accessing the same file handler and moving the "current pointer" concurrently without any synchronisation. To get this back to being correct you need to protect the file descriptor with a mutex. All the locking / unlocking will make it slower that opening the file once per thread.

Your first solution was better (correct and fast).